# How to get specific user code from address label

Tags: php, regex, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get user code from package label which contains address and 6 digit and sometimes 2 prefix with 6 digit. First of all, I am getting label image then with help of aws textract, I take text. But inside of text there can be sometimes 6 digit another code.

I tried a `(\s\d{6}\s)|((\.)\d{6}\s)|(\s[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}\s)` regex with `preg_match_all`.

Is there any solution which can help me to find that code?

Note there is address which is always static and may be there is any function which will search nearby that address?

Example of label. Searched for --> <--:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt --> 913847 <-- ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua --> 913847 <--.
--> TK913847 <-- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: Like `preg_match_all('~\b(?:[a-zA-Z]{2})?\d{6}(?!\S)~', $text, $matches)`?

Comment: You can split the string at --> then split the results again at <-- and take the value of first element of result array

Comment: @prasadK i have added --> <-- for just to show where user code can be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
preg_match_all('/address\s+\K(?:[A-Z]{2})?\d{6}\b/i', $string, $matches)
```

**Note**: Not `preg_match`. Use `preg_match_all` to get all matches from your text.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/IDKzsu/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  address                  'address'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]{2}                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{6}                    digits (0-9) (6 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this would do all you need:

```php
preg_match_all('#\b(([\w]{2})?[\d]{6})\b#ms', $input, $matches);
```

Matches the following code examples:

- AA123456
- bb123456
- 123456

But won't match if part of a term thanks to boundaries such as:

- lorem123456
- code123456aa

Comment: I have used preg match as i said. But problem is that there can be another 6 digit number which is not user code. Another thing is i am getting user data using that code and there can be more than 5-6 companies from where i should check for that code.